# Как проверить определен ли typedef?

Tags: c, c++

Где-то в заголовках есть определение типа вида

```
typedef enum { SUCCESS = 0 } status;
```

Ниже по коду возникает потребность определить тип заново

```
typedef enum { FAILURE = 0 } status;
```

Очевидно, что защититься можно директивами препроцессора

```
#ifndef STATUS
#define STATUS
    typedef enum { SUCCESS = 0 } status;
#endif
```

Но, к сожалению, менять заголовки нельзя. Поэтому вопрос такой: как проверить при определении typedef, что такой typedef еще не определен?

Comment: @asdf Никак.

Comment: а может определить свой тип status в отдельном namespace и использовать его.

Comment: Странные у Вас потребности. Сильно напоминает извращение. Всё-таки 0 это SUCCESS или FAILURE? И так ли их необходимо запихивать в один тип? (Функции, которые их возвращают -- они ведь разные?)

Comment: Я пока не понял цель такого извращения какова? Автор, прошу ответить.

Заодно появилась мысль, что здесь можно использовать шаблоны. Они ж ведь умеют всякие хитрые вещи делать. В т.ч. и отвечать на каверзные вопросы программистов, например, POD ли это тип или нет.

Comment: Нужно в старом коде убрать предупреждения компилятора. Код по возможности желательно изменять минимальным образом. И ряд предупреждений был таков, что показалось неизбежным переопределение typedef'a.

Comment: Ну, дык, расскажите о том какие же предупреждения выдавал компилятор и на какие строчки. Иначе ценность данного вопроса для меня стремиться к нулю, т.к. не ясно, что же является исходной ситуацией.

Answer (score 2):

Проверить - никак нельзя.Но можно поступить таким образом:

```
//то что есть изначально
typedef enum { SSUCCESS = 0 } status;

//то что делаем мы
#ifndef STATUS 
#define STATUS status
#else
#undef STATUS
#define STATUS status
#endif

//далее по коду
typedef enum { FAILURE = 0 } status_def1;
#ifndef STATUS 
#define STATUS status_def1
#else
#undef STATUS
#define STATUS status_def1
#endif

//и во всех случаях, используем STATUS !!!
STATUS eResult;
```

Comment: Да, замечательно. Теперь попробуйте сравнить `eResult` с `FAILURE`.

Comment: !Да, замечательно. Теперь попробуйте сравнить eResult с FAILURE.
@Котик_хочет_кушать 
http://pastebin.com/VaH1Kz1p

Comment: Другое дело что все это не очень удобно и костыли, но это дело уже программиста, решившего использовать подобный трюк :)

Comment: А не проще конструкцию

      #ifndef STATUS 
      #define STATUS status
      #else
      #undef STATUS
      #define STATUS status
      #endif


Свести к 

      #ifdef STATUS 
      #undef STATUS      
      #endif
      
      #define STATUS status

????????